# "There was" vs "it was"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

In my native language *there was* and *it was* can be translated the same in the following text:

> I had been playing this game two years ago. ***There was***/***It was*** interesting.

What exact construction must be used in this case? Can you provide an answer along with explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer goes perfectly with "It was". With "there" (here in your sentence) you would generally have to describe a 'place' or 'thing' or a 'noun'. For example "There was a kid who did this or that etc". However with "It was" it is much more simple and grammatical.

"There was/is" is commonly used in English to introduce new info into the discourse. "There" is a dummy pronoun here.